# Are AspectJ aspects Singletons?

Tags: java, aspectj

When creating aspects using the [Aspect annotation](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect.java) as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspects.html), is it possible to use this annotation with a class that contains a state (e.g. member variables that change as soon as a pointcut is hit)? Or in other words: is an aspect class a singleton? The source code of the annotation suggests something like this, but I cannot find more details in the documentation.

An example: here is an aspect that counts how often a method has been called. The aspect stores the number of invocations in a map and prints out the map:

```java
@Aspect
public class CountAspect {

    private Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>(); 

    @Before("execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void countMethodCalls(JoinPoint jp) {
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        counter.merge(methodName, 1, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

When testing this aspect everthing works as expected. When calling methods `a`, `b` and `c` several times, the output is

```
{main=1}
{a=1, main=1}
{a=1, b=1, main=1}
{a=1, b=1, c=1, main=1}
{a=2, b=1, c=1, main=1}
{a=3, b=1, c=1, main=1}
```

Is this result reliable? Or does my example only work because I have a rather simple example here?

Could it happen that in a more complex scenario, a second instance of `CountAspect` would be created by the AspectJ runtime and thus I would lose data collected in the `counter` map until then?

I am using Load-Time Weaving if that matters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612156/how-aspect-with-component-annotation-works-under-the-hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AspectJ knows multiple instantiation models, one of which (and the default) is singleton. You find more information in the [AspectJ manual](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#aspect-instantiation). There you will see the following instatiation models:

- `perthis`: one aspect instance per **caller** instance of each matched pointcut
- `pertarget`: one aspect instance per **callee** instance of each matched pointcut
- `percflow`:  one aspect instance per entering a certain **control flow**
- `percflowbelow`: one aspect instance per entering a certain **control flow below the intercepted one** (everything called by the intercepted method)

There is one more instantiation model described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/pertypewithin.html):

- `pertypewithin`: one aspect instance per **type (class)** as specified by the pointcut

---

So yes, your aspect as shown in the sample code is a singleton, you can rely on it. Whether you are using compile time weaving, binary weaving or load time weaving does not matter, except maybe if in a container like an application server you deliberately create different weaver instances via class-loader isolation or so.