# Does an @Aspect have to be a @Component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I made a tiny app to check a few things. Here's the code (assume all the files are in the same package)

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Config {
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SomeBean {
    public SomeBean() {
        System.out.println("Creating SomeBean...");
    }

    public String someAspectedMethod() {
        return "some string";
    }
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component // note this
public class SomeAspect {

    public SomeAspect() {
        System.out.println("Creating SomeAspect...");
    }

    @Around("execution(String SomeBean.someAspectedMethod())")
    public Object methodAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Running methodAdvice()..."); // never gets printed
        Object object;
        try {
            object = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        SomeBean someBean = context.getBean(SomeBean.class);
        String returnedVal = someBean.someAspectedMethod();
        System.out.println(returnedVal);
        System.out.println(returnedVal.getClass());
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Creating SomeAspect...
Creating SomeBean...
Running methodAspect()...
some string
class java.lang.String
```

I noticed that once I remove the `@Component` annotation, the aspect is no longer applied

```java
@Aspect
// @Component
public class SomeAspect {
```

Console output:

```java
Creating SomeBean...
some string
class java.lang.String
```

Which begs the question: why isn't `@Aspect` a `@Component` (stereotype annotation) just like `@Service`, `@Repository` and a few others? And if `@Component` is not necessary for aspect classes, then why does the lack of it effectively disables my aspect?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612156/how-aspect-with-component-annotation-works-under-the-hood) doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Aspect` is part of the AspectJ library, which is a stand-alone library that shipped with Spring and therefore, Spring can't change the `@Aspect` annotation source code to add the meta `@Component` (spring can't make `@Aspect` a stereotype in another word)

`@Aspect` is part of aspectj annotations: `org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect`

for

> if @Component is not necessary for aspect classes

`@Component` is there just to register the Aspect in the application context via component scan (`@ComponentScan` that you add to `Config` class let Spring search for stereotype annotations and register them in the application context)

Comment: Thank you! Does a non-managed `@Aspect` (not marked as a `@Component`) ever make sense?

Comment: * or declared in a `@Configuration` class

Comment: no, it should be registered in the application context so Spring can dynamically proxies other beans in order to add the advices in their right places at run-time

Comment: Instead of `@Component`, you could also use a `@Bean` factory method in your config class. A non-managed `@Aspect` makes a whole lot of sense when it is a native AspectJ one, used via either load-time orcompile-time weaving. Then a `@Component` annotation would even be counter-productive, because it would cause the native aspect to be picked up again by Spring, which would then try to use it for Spring AOP, too.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, the `@Aspect` annotation is not directly related to being a stereotype annotation like `@Component`, `@Service`, or `@Repository`. Stereotype annotations are used to indicate that a class fulfills a specific role in the application, and they are often used in conjunction with component scanning to automatically discover and register those components in the Spring context.

While `@Component`, `@Service`, and `@Repository` are all stereotype annotations, `@Aspect` serves a different purpose. It is used to declare a class as an aspect, which is a modular unit of cross-cutting concerns in Spring AOP (Aspect-Oriented Programming). Aspects are not meant to be automatically discovered by component scanning like typical Spring components.

When you apply the `@Component` annotation to an aspect class, you're telling Spring to treat the aspect as a regular Spring component and manage its lifecycle. This is why you see the aspect being created and its advice being applied when it's a `@Component`.

However, if you remove the `@Component` annotation from your aspect class, Spring no longer treats it as a managed component. As a result, the aspect is not registered with the Spring context, and its advice won't be applied to the target methods.

To summarize:

1. The `@Aspect` annotation is not a stereotype annotation like `@Component`. It's used to define a class as an aspect to handle cross-cutting concerns.
2. Adding `@Component` to an aspect class makes Spring treat it as a managed component, and the aspect's advice will be applied.
3. Removing `@Component` from an aspect class will prevent Spring from managing it, and the aspect's advice won't be applied.

So, while `@Component` can be used with an aspect class to manage its lifecycle, it's not a requirement for aspects to function properly. Aspects can be used effectively without being managed components, but you'll need to manually register them with Spring's AOP configuration if they are not discovered via component scanning.

Comment: Does an `@Aspect` not managed by Spring ever make sense?

Comment: beans registered via java-config are still valid managed components

Comment: @JoreJoh An `@Aspect` not mananaged by Spring does make sense, when you are not using spring-aop, but "normal" AspectJ with compile-time-weaving, or load-time-weaving